# Reduce repetition in java code with dynamic object naming?

Tags: java, object, dynamic

A testcase aims to access an array of machines via dynamic objects names, is something like the following possible?

```
    String[][] mysession = new String["Win7"]["firefox"]; //mysessionWin7firefox
    String[][] mysession = new String["Win7"]["ie"]; //mysessionWin7ie
    String[][] mysession = new String["Win10"]["edge"]; //mysessionWin10edge

    mysession[Win7][firefox] = new RemoteWebDriver...;
    mysession[Win7][firefox].get(myurl);
    mysession[Win10][edge].doStuff();
```

Comment: Strings are NOT compared using ``==``! Use equals instead!

Comment: @f1sh Not always. It's much faster to use == if you can intern the Strings.

Comment: @FMC how much faster, as a percentage of overall runtime, in the OP's context? We need data to see if it's worth the effort, complexity, and downsides of `intern` abuse. Please provide numbers for your claim.

Comment: @David Java doesn't have associative arrays (dictionaries) in the syntax you show. It does have `java.util.Map` and its implementations, which are exactly equivalent.

Comment: @LewBloch f1sh's comment implied that Strings should never be compared with ==, I was just clarifying that if you intern the Strings you can use the == operator.

Comment: How about something like this to setup multiple node sessions for use within a single testcase, except that it seems I can't make an object array with RemoteWebDriver, as a might do with a new String[5];

mysession = new RemoteWebDriver[5];

mysession[3]=(new URL("http://"+ipaddress+":5555/wd/hub"), variable)

mysession[3].get("http:\\www.google.com");

mysession[3].quit();